# How to count values in a certain range in a Numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a NumPy array of  values. I want to count how many of these values are in a specific range say x<100 and x>25. I have read about the counter, but it seems to only be valid for specif values not ranges of values. I have searched, but have not found anything regarding my specific problem. If someone could point me towards the proper documentation I would appreciate it. Thank you

I have tried this

```
   X = array(X)
   for X in range(25, 100):
       print(X)
```

But it just gives me the numbers in between 25 and 99.

**EDIT**
The data I am using was created by another program. I then used a script to read the data and store it as a list. I then took the list and turned it in to an array using array(r).

**Edit**

The result of running

```
 >>> a[0:10]
 array(['29.63827346', '40.61488812', '25.48300065', '26.22910525',
   '42.41172923', '20.15013315', '34.95323355', '13.03604098',
   '29.71097606', '9.53222141'], 
  dtype='<U11')
```

Comment: @Senderle that did it thank you so much!! I tried Sven's method after reconverting the array and it worked perfectly! Thanks again

Answer (score 91, accepted):

If your array is called `a`, the number of elements fulfilling `25 < x < 100` is

```
((25 < a) & (a < 100)).sum()
```

The expression `(25 < a) & (a < 100)` results in a Boolean array with the same shape as `a` with the value `True` for all elements that satisfy the condition.  Summing over this Boolean array treats `True` values as `1` and `False` values as `0`.

Comment: @SvenI tried your method, but got this error ``TypeError: unorderable types: int() < numpy.ndarray()``

Comment: @Surfcast23: [Works for me.](https://gist.github.com/1975690)  What version of NumPy and Python are you using?

Comment: Works for me under Python 3.2.2 and numpy 1.6.1.

Comment: Oh, I know what might be happening.  The unorderable types error is the one you'd get if the dtype was something unexpected -- e.g. 2 < numpy.array(range(10), dtype=str) gives exactly this message.

Comment: @DSM I think you are right. I just don't know how to go about fixing it.

Comment: +1: This is the most memory-efficient solution I can think of, when one wants speed and a concise NumPy code.

Comment: Will this do a single or two passes over the array? In my case I have a (large) array of intervals and I'd like to check if another vector of values is element-wise within the intervals.

Comment: @Bar The expression in this answer will perform four passes over the array – one each for the two comparison operators, one pass for `&` and one pass for `.sum()`.  (Technically, some of the passes aren't over the input array, but rather over intermediary arrays of the same size.)  For an array of intervals, you might be better off using `numpy.histogram()` or `numpy.digitize()`, but you need to measure to be sure.  Please ask a separate question if this information isn't enough.

Answer (score 12):

Building on Sven's good approach, you can also do the slightly more explicit:

```
numpy.count_nonzero((25 < a) & (a < 100))
```

This first creates an array of booleans with one boolean for each input number in array `a`, and then count the number of non-False (i.e. True) values (which gives the number of matching numbers).

Note, however, that this approach is twice as slow as Sven's `.sum()` approach, on an array of 100k numbers (NumPy 1.6.1, Python 2.7.3)–about 300 µs versus 150 µs.

Answer (score 11):

You could use `histogram`. Here's a basic usage example:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.random.random(size=100) * 100 
>>> numpy.histogram(a, bins=(0.0, 7.3, 22.4, 55.5, 77, 79, 98, 100))
(array([ 8, 14, 34, 31,  0, 12,  1]), 
 array([   0. ,    7.3,   22.4,   55.5,   77. ,   79. ,   98. ,  100. ]))
```

In your particular case, it would look something like this:

```
>>> numpy.histogram(a, bins=(25, 100))
(array([73]), array([ 25, 100]))
```

Additionally, when you have a list of strings, you have to explicitly specify the type, so that `numpy` knows to produce an array of floats instead of a list of strings.

```
>>> strings = [str(i) for i in range(10)]
>>> numpy.array(strings)
array(['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'], 
      dtype='|S1')
>>> numpy.array(strings, dtype=float)
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])
```

Comment: @Surfcast23, yeah, this one is more general-purpose, but if you really only need one bin, [Sven](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9560228/577088)'s will be faster.

Comment: I ran the code and got ``(array([-481], dtype=int32), array([ 25, 100]))`` What concerns me is the negative sign how should I interpret it?

Comment: @Surfcast23, so many strange results. I'm starting to think there's something you haven't told us about your data. What's the `dtype` of this array?

Comment: @ Senderle the data is just an array of floats here are the first several values
`40.61488812
25.48300065
26.22910525
42.41172923
20.15013315
34.95323355
13.03604098
29.71097606
9.53222141
13.08244932
38.04509923
20.16046549
29.40530862`

Answer (score 6):

Sven's answer is the way to do it if you don't wish to further process matching values.
The following two examples return copies with only the matching values:

```
np.compress((25 < a) & (a < 100), a).size
```

Or:

```
a[(25 < a) & (a < 100)].size
```

Example interpreter session:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.randint(200,size=100)
>>> a
array([194, 131,  10, 100, 199, 123,  36,  14,  52, 195, 114, 181, 138,
       144,  70, 185, 127,  52,  41, 126, 159,  39,  68, 118, 124, 119,
        45, 161,  66,  29, 179, 194, 145, 163, 190, 150, 186,  25,  61,
       187,   0,  69,  87,  20, 192,  18, 147,  53,  40, 113, 193, 178,
       104, 170, 133,  69,  61,  48,  84, 121,  13,  49,  11,  29, 136,
       141,  64,  22, 111, 162, 107,  33, 130,  11,  22, 167, 157,  99,
        59,  12,  70, 154,  44,  45, 110, 180, 116,  56, 136,  54, 139,
        26,  77, 128,  55, 143, 133, 137,   3,  83])
>>> np.compress((25 < a) & (a < 100),a).size
34
>>> a[(25 < a) & (a < 100)].size
34
```

The above examples use a "bit-wise and" (&) to do an element-wise computation along the two boolean arrays which you create for comparison purposes.
Another way to write Sven's excellent answer, for example, is:

```
np.bitwise_and(25 < a, a < 100).sum()
```

The boolean arrays contain `True` values when the condition matches, and `False` when it doesn't.
A bonus aspect of boolean values is that `True` is equivalent to 1 and `False` to 0.

Comment: @Sevn and Adam, I am still pretty new to python ~6 months not very consistently though. Can you guys explain how and why your scripts work? Thank you

Comment: @Surfcast23: I added a bit of an explanation. Keep at it!

Comment: Thank *you* -- for the good question. It is fun to see such a wide range of approaches and solutions.

Comment: It seems more natural to use `numpy.logical_and()` instead of `numpy.bitwise_and()` here.  The result will be the same, but it feels more "conceptually right".

Comment: Contrary to Sven's solution, this creates an additional array, which consumes memory for not much benefit.

Comment: @SvenMarnach. Suppose I want to do further processing on the values within the range from the array instead of just counting them. How will the code be?

Answer (score 2):

I think @Sven Marnach answer is quite nice, because it operates in on the numpy array itself which will be fast and efficient (C implementation).

I like to put the test into one condition like `25 < x < 100`, so I would probably do it something like this:

`len([x for x in a.ravel() if 25 < x < 100])`

Comment: Nice. To use gen-expr: `sum(1 for i in a.ravel() if 25 < i < 100)`

Comment: that is good too.  at first i tried to use `len()` on a generator and to my surprise it doesn't work

Comment: @wim: `len()` does not work with generator expressions because iterators do not generally have a finite length. This is why the `sum(1 …)` approach is better: it has a fixed and much smaller memory footprint, since you don't have to create an intermediate list.