# Count number of occurrences in repeated range

Tags: python, numpy

I want to count the number of occurrences/events within a range given a Numpy array of numbers.

For example, let's consider the array called `arr` and the result called `arr` via the function `event_count`:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([0, 0.2, 0.3, 1, 1.5, 2])
bins = [0, 1, 2]
res = event_count(arr, bins=bins)
print(res)
>>> [3, 2, 1]
```

This is somewhat similar to what a historgram performs with it's `bin` argument, but I want to do it without creating a histogram plot. This is also similar to what `bincount` does, but I want a range instead of specific instances. This is also similar to this [Finding Occurrences in a Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560207/how-to-count-values-in-a-certain-range-in-a-numpy-array) question, but I want a repeated range.

Comment: You can use the histogram functions in numpy w/o plotting.  `np.histogram' returns the bins and the edges.

Comment: @roadrunner66 Aw jeez! Should I leave this up for future reference or delete it?

Comment: answer your own question, or see if roadrunner does. For posterity, someone should answer if possible so that someone else can utilize it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [use a histogram without using it to plot](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html). Here's an example using the previous code:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([0, 0.2, 0.3, 1, 1.5, 2])
bins = [0, 1, 2, 3]
res = np.histogram(arr, bins=bins)
print(res[0])
>>> [3, 2, 1]
```