# How to count values in a certain range in a Numpy array? (Does not work)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have already checked this thread [How to count values in a certain range in a Numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560207/how-to-count-values-in-a-certain-range-in-a-numpy-array)  but their answer does not seem to work.

I have a numpy array of 2000 floats called data:

```
print(type(data)) --> <type 'list'>
print(type(data[0])) --> <type 'numpy.float64'>
```

And I have 2 variables to form a range, minV and maxV:

```
print(type(minV)) --> <type 'float'>
print(type(maxV)) --> <type 'float'>
```

If I try the solution given in the link mentioned above, I receive this exception:

```
((minV < data) & (data < maxV)).sum()

AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'sum'
```

And indeed, that expression is a boolean:

```
print(type( (minV < data) & (data < minV) ) ) --> <type 'bool'>
print( ( (minV < data) & (data < minV) ) ) --> True
```

The python version I am using is Python 2.7.3 -- EPD 7.3-2 (64-bit)
Numpy version is 1.6.1

System is Linux (Although I ignore if that is important).

Thanks.

Comment: You are operating on lists instead of numpy.arrays! Try `data = np.array(data)` before trying the `< & >` operations.

Comment: Yep. That's it. Sorry for my silliness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are using python 2 because comparing a list and a number doesn't raise a `TypeError` in your case.

But in order to use element-wise comparison (`<`, `>`, `&`) you need to convert your list to a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array(data)
((minV < data) & (data < maxV)).sum()
```

should work. For example:

```
data = list(range(1000))
minV = 100
maxV = 500
data = np.array(data)
((minV < data) & (data < maxV)).sum() # returns 399
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `data` is not an array. Please check it. The suggested solution does work with arrays. Perhaps at some point `data` became a number or something.

Comment: Let's keep opened minds here, yes? He said `data` is an array. The code print shows a list. Conclusion - data is maybe tampered with and changed type.