# Perform mulitple comparisons (interval) in a Numpy array in a single pass

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

I have a situation similar to the "[Count values in a certain range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9560207/209882)" question, but instead of a column-vector I have a matrix `intervals` with two columns `[upper, lower]` and another column vector  `true_values`.

I want to check whether the values in the `true_values` vector are within the ranges defined `[upper, lower]`, element wise.

The answer provided in the linked question would do 4 passes:

`((true_values >= intervals[:, 0]) & (true_values <= intervals[:, 1])).sum()`

One pass for each greater/less than check, one for the and clause, and one for the `sum`.

Given that these are potentially huge matrices, I'm wondering if it's possible to reduce the number of passes necessary, ideally to one pass for the interval checks, and one for the sum (I think unavoidable), I was thinking something like broadcasting a function over `intervals`' rows.

Here's a minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
n_samples = 2000
n_features = 10
rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
X = rng.normal(size=(n_samples, n_features))
w = rng.normal(size=n_features)
# simple linear function without noise
y = np.dot(X, w)

gbrt = GradientBoostingRegressor(loss='quantile', alpha=0.95)

gbrt.fit(X, y)
# Get upper interval
upper_interval = gbrt.predict(X)
# Get lower interval
gbrt.set_params(alpha=0.05)
gbrt.fit(X, y)
lower_interval = gbrt.predict(X)
intervals = np.concatenate((lower_interval[:, np.newaxis], upper_interval[:, np.newaxis]), axis=1)
# This is 4 passes:
perc_correct_intervals = ((y >= intervals[:, 0]) & (y <= intervals[:, 1])).sum() / y.shape[0]
```

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Comment: You can use a loop and @njit it?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque added a code example

Answer (score 0):

some savings with `np.count_nonzero` vs `.sum()`,  more if you don't really need to make the `intervals` matrix for other uses

```
%%timeit
intervals = np.concatenate((lower_interval[:, np.newaxis], upper_interval[:, np.newaxis]), axis=1);
perc_correct_intervals = ((y >= intervals[:, 0]) & (y <= intervals[:, 1])).sum() / y.shape[0]

15.7 µs ± 78.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)


%%timeit
np.count_nonzero(np.less(lower_interval, y)*np.less(y, upper_interval))/y.size

3.93 µs ± 28 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: The intervals matrix must be computed. Still, using `count_nonzero` gives a slight advantage (12-14%). The number of passes over the matrix remains the same as far as I can tell.