# count the number of array elements that belong to a given numerical range

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, scipy

Given an numpy array and a given numerical range, e.g., [0.2, 0.3]. Are there any functions to calculate the count of array elements that belong to this numerical range? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count values in a certain range in a Numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560207/how-to-count-values-in-a-certain-range-in-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869173/numpy-find-elements-within-range) you can use `np.where` and `np.logical_and` to get what you want, also apply `len()` to the result:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 14, 15, 56])

b = np.where(np.logical_and(a>=6, a<=10))
# returns (array([3, 4, 5]),)

len(b)
# returns 3
```

Comment: Hi Wavy, I tried to use your answer to test one of my code, but it failed. I have opened a question in the following link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58585533/regarding-the-failure-of-counting-the-number-of-array-elements-belonging-to-a-gi      would you mind to take a look at it? Thanks.